# C memory management in server application

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, posix, http-proxy

I am student and I am writing HTTP proxy application in C. I have trouble with memory management. In all my previous applications I simply wrote a wrapper around malloc which aborted when malloc failed.

```
void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ptr;

    assert(size);

    ptr = malloc(size);
    if (!ptr) 
        abort();

    return ptr;
}
```

This I now find insufficient as I just want to refuse client and continue serving other clients when memory allocation fails due to temporary shortage of memory. If I don't want to clutter my code with checks after each malloc call (I have quite lot of them per function in parsing code), what are other options to handle memory management and which one is the best for my purposes and how what is a common way for server applications to handle memory management and shortage of memory?

Consider this function from my current code which parses one line from header portion of HTTP message (xstrndup calls xmalloc):

```
int http_header_parse(http_hdr_table *t, const char *s)
{
    const char *p;
    const char *b;
    char *tmp_name;
    char *tmp_value;
    int ret = -1;

    assert(t);
    assert(s);

    p = b = s;

    /* field name */
    for (; ; p++) {
        if (*p == ':') {
            if (p-b <= 0) goto out;
            tmp_name = xstrndup(b, p-b);
            b = ++p;
            break;
        }

        if (is_ctl_char(*p) || is_sep_char(*p)) goto out;
    }

    while (*p == ' ' || *p == '\t') {
        p++; b++;
    }

    /* field value */
    for (; ; p++) {
        if (is_crlf(p)) {
            if (p-b <= 0) goto err_value;
            tmp_value = xstrndup(b, p-b);
            p += 2;
            break;
        }

        if (!*p) goto err_value;
    }
    http_hdr_table_set(t, tmp_name, tmp_value);

    ret = 0;
    xfree(tmp_value);
err_value:
    xfree(tmp_name);
out:
    return ret;
}
```

I would like to keep things simple and handle memory allocation errors at one place and to not clutter code with malloc error handling code. What should I do? Thank you.

P.S: I am writing the application to run on POSIX/Unix-like systems. Also feel free to criticize my current coding style and practices.

Comment: Thank you all for answers it was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a relatively low level language like C, then you shouldn't be too worried about adding something like `if(tmp_value == NULL) goto out;` in 2 places.

If you can't stand the idea of 2 trivial lines of extra code, then maybe try a language that supports exceptions properly (e.g. C++) and add throw/try/catch instead. *Note: I really don't like C++, but using C++ would have to make more sense than implementing your own "exception like" features and an entire layer of automated resource de-allocation in C.*

Comment: It's no that I can't stand it, I am just trying to ease memory management and add a bit of robustness to my application. I am trying to learn program in C and I was sure the big and robust applications don't do just check on plain malloc's return value each time, so I asked how is it solved in these applications. Maybe other language would be more suitable but I am trying to learn how to do things in C.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a system that supports fork(), which linux does, you can run each client connection in it's own process.  When a client connection is first established, you fork your main process into a child process to handle the rest of the request.  Then you can abort() like you always have and only the specific client connection is affected.  This is a classic unix server model.

If you don't want to or can't use fork(), you need to abort the request by throwing an exception.  In C, that would be done by using setjump() when the connection is first established and then calling longjump() when out of memory is detected.  This will reset execution and the stack back to where setjump() was called.

The problem is, this will leak all the resources allocated up to that point (for example, other memory allocations that had succeeded up to the point of getting out of memory).  So additionally, your memory allocator will have to track all the memory allocations for each request.  When longjump() is called, the setjump() return location will then have to free all the memory that was associated with the aborted request.

This is what apache does using pools.  Apache uses pools to track resource allocations so it can auto free them in the case of an abort or because the code just didn't free it: http://www.apachetutor.org/dev/pools.

You should also consider the pool model and not just simply wrap malloc() so one client can't use up all the memory in the system.

Comment: That's a very risky advice. `setjump` and `longjump` can be used to implement something like exceptions, but they're much more low level and very hard to implement properly.

Comment: @ugoren - I agree the advice is risky and thanks for pointing that out as I did not caveat my answer much - it's also a massive undertaking but if it's C, setjump/longjump is all I know for how to implement it - now there may be some library to use to make it easier, but that's a slippery slope - might as well go all the way then and use Apache.

Comment: The question is what is "it", which he wants to implement. If it's exceptions, you're right - this is the only way. If it's a server without memory leaks, there are many ways.

Answer (score 1):

Modern languages give you garbage collection and exceptions. C doesn't, so you have to work hard. There's no magical solution here.

Some tips:

1. Create a session structure, and keep all your allocated memory pointed from it. When the session is aborted, always call a cleanup function. This way, even if you have to check for failures in many places, at least all failures are handled the same way.
2. You can even create a `session_allocate()` function, which allocates memory and keeps it on a linked list pointed from the session structure. Everything you allocate using this function would be freed when the session is destroy.
3. Try to concentrate all allocations in the beginning of the session. After you've allocated all you need, the rest of your code won't need to worry about failures.

Comment: Bohem's GC library offer garbage collection in C. It is not perfect, it is conservative, but in practice works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to use [Boehm's GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) by using its `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc` (you won't need to call `free` or `GC_free`); its 
`GC_oom_fn` function pointer (called internally from `GC_malloc` when no memory is available any more) can be set to your particular out of memory handler (which would deny the incoming HTTP request, perhaps with a `longjmp`)

The major advantage of using Boehm GC is that you don't care any more about `free`-ing your dynamically allocated data (provided it was allocated using `GC_malloc` or friends, e.g. `GC_malloc_atomic` for data without any pointers inside).

Notice that memory management is not a modular property. The liveness of some given data is a whole program property, see [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) wikipage, and [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) programming idiom.

Answer (score 0):

You could of course use `alloca`, but that has issues that mean it must be used with care.  Alternatively, you can write your code so that you minimise and localise the use of malloc.  For example your function above could be rewritten to localise the allocations:

```
static size_t field_name_length(const char *s)
{
    const char *p = s;
    for ( ; *p != ':'; ++p) {
        if (is_ctl_char(*p) || is_sep_char(*p))
            return 0;
    }
    return (size_t) (p - s);
}

static size_t value_length(const char *s)
{
    const char *p = s;
    for (; *p && !is_crlf(p); p+=2) {
        /* nothing */
    }
    return *p ? (size_t) (p - s) : 0;
}

int http_header_parse(http_hdr_table *t, const char *s)
{
    const char *v;
    int ret = -1;
    size_t v_len = 0;
    size_t f_len = field_name_length(s);

    if (f_len) {
        v = s + f_len + 1;
        v = s + strspn(s, " \t");
        v_len = value_length(s);
    }
    if (v_len > 0 && f_len > 0) {
        /* Allocation is localised to this block */
        const char *name = xstrndup(s, f_len);
        const char *value = xstrndup(v, v_len);

        if (name && value) {
            http_hdr_table_set(t, name, value);
            ret = 0;
        }
        xfree(value);
        xfree(name);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Or, even better, you could modify `http_hdr_table_set` to accept the pointers and lengths and avoid allocation completely.

Comment: Can I ask why the explicit type conversions in return statements?

Comment: The pointer arithmetic results in a long (or similar) integer but the return type is size_t (an unsigned type).  Without the cast, the compiler may throw a warning (eg. with clang if -Wsign-conversion is enabled).